# How can I replace a text on the header on a word document template?

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

I'm currently working on a R markdown report automation that outputs different report as a Word file. I'm currently using a template provided by the client that has headers, footnotes and page number. What I needed was a way to have a variable header since each word file contains different report number and those report number are placed in a header.

I can't seem to find a right solution for this but the header of the template looks like this:
[image]

The idea is I will set the report number as parameter on the R markdown file like this:

```
---
params:
   report_no: 'XXX-111-A'
title: ""
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: "template.docx"
---
```

Then the  on the template will be replaced by the one I set on the parameter and the output will look like this:

[image]

This should be set as a header since this should be repeated across all the pages on the report.

Answer (score 0):

R Markdown uses Pandoc for Markdown to Microsoft Word document (DOCX) convertion. Pandoc does NOT have support to replace placeholders in the DOCX template with the value of variables in the Markdown.

For your case, you can use a post-processing to fix the header. The `.docx` file can be open as a `.zip` file and you can edit the file `word/header1.xml`.

For example,

[image: Screenshot of DOCX file open with LibreOffice]

has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:hdr xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14 w15"><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Header"/><w:bidi w:val="0"/><w:jc w:val="left"/><w:rPr></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr></w:rPr><w:t>Report ID_GOES_HERE</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:hdr>
```

in the `word/header1.xml`. And I can replace `ID_GOES_HERE` with the report number.

Answer (score 0):

### Use the StyleRef Field in your Headers / Footers

Here are some references:

- [StyleRef Field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-styleref-field-4ad557c2-c8ab-48ba-8fe3-901d0a5775d0) (Microsoft documentation)
- [StyleRef Field](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF) (in my page on Fields)
- [More Links about the StyleRef Field](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styleref.htm) (one of my pages)

The key idea is that you create and use a custom style to use in your document. It then will show where the StyleRef field that refers to that styles is in the header.

If your users can remember to use the Style, I think the StyleRef field will work fine for you. You could have a Content Control in the Style referenced by the field in the body of your document, perhaps in a cover page.

If your template will be used with multiple languages, take a look at
[StyleRef Fields and Local Style Names](https://www.thedoctools.com/word-macros-tips/word-tips/styleref-fields-and-language-specific-style-names/) by Word MVP Lene Fredborg

### An alternative would be to use one of the Cover Page Document Properties with a Copy in the Header

This is discussed in my Answer here. [Repeating Text Using Mapped Content Controls](https://superuser.com/questions/1761947/repeating-text-in-word-file-via-content-controls-or-styleref-produces-inconsiste/1767481#1767481) - Super User

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create my desired output using the headers_replace_all_text function on R and using an edited template on my YAML code at the start.

```
---
params:
   report_no: 'XXX-111-A'
title: ""
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: "template_edited.docx"
---


``{r}
#get value from yaml 
report_no <- params$report_no 

#change the header of the template to the report number
doc <- read_docx("template.docx")
doc <- headers_replace_all_text(doc, "report number", report_no, only_at_cursor=FALSE, ignore.case = TRUE)
print(doc, target = "template_edited.docx")

``
```

I was just not sure why using the <> character on the template and replacing the text with the <> character (e.g. < report number >) won't make it work. So I just replaced the text on my template with just *report number*.